# upgrade steps from DataStax Enterprise 4.6.1 TO DataStax Enterprise 4.7 with Cassandra 2.1

Tags: cassandra, enterprise, datastax

I'm new to cassandra, can some one provide steps to upgrade  from DataStax Enterprise 4.6.1   TO  DataStax Enterprise 4.7 with Cassandra 2.1

Answer (score 1):

This should get you where you'd like to go: http://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgradeDSE47.html

Since you're new to Cassandra, I suggest reading the docs over and over - even doing this in a test environment first. While upgrades are fairly straight forward (depending on node count and amount of data), there's no real easy way of reverting from Cassandra 2.1 (DSE 4.7) to Cassandra 2.0 (DSE 4.6). So make sure you have snapshots of sstables from DSE 4.6 before proceeding.